# Laravel scheduled task not starting up

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I use Laravel 6 and have the following setup:

```
$schedule
  ->command('auctions:update_discounts_featured')
  ->everyMinute()
  ->withoutOverlapping()
  ->runInBackground();
```

It can work fine for days, but every once in a while it just stops. Other tasks defined here continue to work fine.

I don't see any lock files in storage/framework.

What might be causing it and how to fix it?

Comment: I think it stops working when there's a fatal error inside it. Is there way to restart/recover the task after fatal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tinker/debug with an instance of the event class, you can dump like :

```
$event = $schedule
  ->command('auctions:update_discounts_featured')
  ->everyMinute()
  ->withoutOverlapping()
  ->runInBackground();
dd($event->expression); // "* * * * *"
```

To trigger this method, run artisan:

> php artisan
>   "* * * * *"

See also [Tips for Using Laravel’s Scheduler](https://laravel-news.com/tips-for-using-laravels-scheduler)